# Not getting background color at proper place

Tags: css, html, web

I am a beginner to website design and development and also learning it. As a beginner i creating a site which is old bbc news website from the following  archive link http://web.archive.org/web/20140402131524/http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk
so i am stcked at watch/listen part the backgroun color orange to link which is below the video is aligning to the right side of it according to my code 
following is my code...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 15px;
}
.watch {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  color: #505050;
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  float: right;
  width: 336px;
}
#videoa {
  float: left;
  background-color: #d1700e;
  position: relative;
  top: -84px;
  left: 25px;
}
#videoa a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 5px;
}
.watchhead {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 8px;
}
#WatchListenlogo {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 22px;
  right: 10px;
}
#rightarrow {
  float: left;
  border-right: solid white 1px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="watch">
  <img src="http://s9.tinypic.com/2hd45fp_th.jpg" id="WatchListenlogo" />
  <span class="watchhead">Watch/Listen</span>
  <img src="http://s9.tinypic.com/35c03yr_th.jpg" id="rightarrow" />
  <div id="videoa">
    <img src="http://s9.tinypic.com/j64ufl_th.jpg" />
    <a href="">Titanic letter could fetch &pound; 100,000</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the background color is applied to entire div ie 
videoa{backgroundcolor:#d1700e;}
where as the background should only be applied to link only ie to 
videoa a{background-color:#d1700e;}

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0;
line-height:15px;
}
.watch{
position:relative;
top:50px;
right:50px;
color:#505050;
line-height:24px;
background-color:#eeeeee;
float:right;
width:336px;
}
#videoa{                    
float:left;
/*background-color:#d1700e;*/
position:relative;
top:-84px;
left:25px;
}
#videoa a{
background-color:#d1700e;
float:left;
color:white;
position:relative;
top:2px;
left:5px;
}
.watchhead{
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bolder;
position:relative;
top:10px;
left:8px;
}
#WatchListenlogo{
float:right;
position:relative;
top:22px;
right:10px;
}
#rightarrow{
float:left;
border-right:solid white 1px;
position:relative;
top:40px;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="watch">
<img src="http://s9.tinypic.com/2hd45fp_th.jpg" id="WatchListenlogo"/>
<span class="watchhead">Watch/Listen</span>
<img src="http://s9.tinypic.com/35c03yr_th.jpg" id="rightarrow"/>
<div id="videoa">  
<img src="http://s9.tinypic.com/j64ufl_th.jpg"/>
<a href="" class="link">Titanic letter could fetch &pound; 100,000</a>   
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```